# ArrayDeque implements Stack?

Tags: java

I've seen this code somewhere:

```
Stack<TreeNode> stack = new ArrayDeque<TreeNode>();
```

My question is, ArrayDeque is not a stack, why the code above is right?

ArrayDeque implements these interfaces:
`Serializable`, `Cloneable`, `Iterable<E>`, `Collection<E>`, `Deque<E>`, `Queue<E>`
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html

But I don't see stack anywhere...
I need help.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't see something like `Deque stack = new ArrayDeque()`?

Comment: Where are the generic types? If the code is used rawtypes I wouldn't trust it.

Comment: code is here: http://n00tc0d3r.blogspot.com/2013/08/implement-iterator-for-binarytree-ii.html

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/KVL9hT) says its invalid

Comment: The line of code in that link is `Stack<TreeNode> stack = new ArrayDeque<TreeNode>();`. At least generics were used! I voted to close as it's just a simple mistake in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code won't compile with standard `Stack` and `ArrayDeque`:

```
Error: java: Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.ArrayDeque to java.util.Stack
```

The only possibility I see is that these classes are not from `java.util` package.

Comment: And you can look at the `import` statements at the top of the source file to get at least a clue as to which `Stack` and `ArrayDeque` classes are being used.  If they are the standard library versions, then the code you saw is just wrong.